# String pre-definition in .h file and using it to filter user input

Tags: c++, string, if-statement, macros, user-input

Consider the following situation:

```
#define YES "y"||"Y"||"yes"||"Yes"||"YES"
#define NO "n"||"N"||"no"||"No"||"NO"
```

With macros being used at the user input.

```
FRW::writeLine(PLAY_AGAIN);
    latestResponse = FRW::getUserInput();
    if (latestResponse == YES)
    {
        retry = false;
    }
    else if (latestResponse == NO)
    {
        retry = true;
    }
```

I am aware that this is wrong and I should actually use...

```
#define YES latestResponse == "y"|| latestResponse == "Y"|| latestResponse == "yes"|| latestResponse == "Yes"|| latestResponse == "YES"
```

... and checking as

```
 if (latestResponse == YES)
    {
        retry = false;
    }
    else if (latestResponse == NO)
    {
        retry = true;
    }
```

Please, can somebody recommend any other way of implementing string macros?
Or should I stay this way?

Comment: I would avoid something like this.

Comment: Better use small inlined functions than a macro.

Comment: never, but NEVER use such kind of macro. This is like negative example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no benefit in using macros this way.

You should rather ask, what is the proper abstraction here? In this case it could be

```
bool is_yes(const std::string &response) {
    return response == "y" || response == "yes" || ...;
}

bool is_no(const std::string &response) {
     // ...
}
```

and then using this in your code.